# Custom WordPress Theme - Menus will not add to nav

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working on a custom WordPress theme for a client. This is the first time that I've created my own theme. I am missing some code, I'm sure of it. Just don't know where to add it and what code to add.

Issue: I can open the customization screen and add a menu, but the menu never shows. I have manually created the nav because it doesn't work. But I'm realizing that this really just needs to be fixed in case they ever want to change their nav. If they don't know how to code, it would make it harder on them.

I'm only experienced with CSS and HTML. I haven't learned PHP but I'm betting that's the issue somewhere...

Comment: To ask an On Topic question, please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/navigation-menus/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the theme folder, open the `header.php` file and insert the following code:

`<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) ); ?>`

And this code goes into your theme's `functions.php` file.

```
function register_custom_menu() {
    register_nav_menu('header-menu',__( 'Header Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_custom_menu' );
```

After that, the changes you make in the customisation screen will appear in the front-end.

Comment: Do I need to put it in any specific location in the header.php file?

Comment: So far this is not working.

Comment: Ok so I think I figured out where to place it. I got the function in the <script> section and placed the other part up where the nav is. Now all of the links are showing up. Now I have to figure out how to style this properly. I may make another post for it. THANK YOU HAREESH!

Comment: Accept and upvote the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: I accepted. But couldn't upvote because I have less than 15 reputation - or so says this website.

Comment: **Strong Warning**: This is NOT a good method, for two reasons: 1. Any functions like the action / register_custom_menu should be added to the `functions.php` file, but *more importantly*, if / when this theme is updated, these changes will **get wiped out**.

Comment: @cale_b my bad. I've made the edit now.

And regarding your other concern, it is not relevant in this case as we're dealing with a custom theme.